# Need a component/library that allows me to export to PSD (Adobe Photoshop's)

Tags: delphi, components, vcl, psd

Does anyone know of a library/component for Delphi that allows exporting graphics to a multilayer PSD?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vampyre Imaging Library](http://imaginglib.sourceforge.net/) can work with PSD, but I am not sure about layers.

Answer (score 0):

[LeadTools](http://www.leadtools.com) supports many graphic formats, including PSD. Don't know if it supports multylayer PSD, though. AFAIK it no longer includes a Delphi wrapper, but it has C/ActiveX interfaces that can be easily used from Delphi.

Comment: LeadTools has their VCL Delphi wrapper for the current version 17.x in beta now. They aren't doing new development for Delphi though.

Comment: we use an older version of lead tools which is quite buggy...one of the most frustrating bugs is it breaks the IDE line counter when you use // for comments in the code.  So the line you get taken to on a compiler error isn't really the line that has the error.  Makes it very difficult to debug.  Hopefully they've fixed that by now!